# Cg problems with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, shader, cg, glew, ogre

I'm working on an OpenGL project on Windows, using GLEW to provide the functionality the provided Windows headers lack. For shader support, I'm using NVIDIA's Cg. All the documentation and code samples I have read indicate that the following is the correct method for loading an using shaders, and I've implemented things this way in my code:

1. Create a Cg context with `cgCreateContext`.
2. Get the latest vertex and pixel shader profiles using `cgGLGetLatestProfile` with `CG_GL_VERTEX` and `CG_GL_FRAGMENT`, respectively. Use `cgGLSetContextOptimalOptions` to create the optimal setup for both profiles.
3. Using these profiles and shaders you have written, create shader programs using `cgCreateProgramFromFile`.
4. Load the shader programs using `cgGLLoadProgram`.

Then, each frame, for an object that uses a given shader:

1. Bind the desired shader(s) (vertex and/or pixel) using `cgGLBindProgram`.
2. Enable the profile(s) for the desired shader(s) using `cgGLEnableProfile`.
3. Retrieve and set any needed uniform shader parameters using `cgGetNamedParameter` and the various parameter setting functions.
4. Render your object normally
5. Clean up the shader by calling `cgGLDisableProfile`

However, things start getting strange. When using a single shader everything works just fine, but the act of loading a second shader with `cgGLLoadProgram` seems to make objects using the first one cease to render. Switching the draw order seems to resolve the issue, but that's hardly a fix. This problem occurs on both my and my partner's laptops (fairly recent machines with Intel integrated chipsets).

I tested the same code on my desktop with a GeForce GTX 260, and everything worked fine. I would just write this off as my laptop GPU not getting along with Cg, but I've successfully built and run programs that use several Cg shaders simultaneously on my laptop using the [OGRE graphics engine](http://www.ogre3d.org) (unfortunately the assignment I'm currently working on is for a computer graphics class, so I can't just use OGRE).

In conclusion, I'm stumped. What is OGRE doing that my code is not? Am I using Cg improperly?

Comment: AFAIK, cgGLEnableProfile needs to be called only during initialization (correspondingly cgGLDisableProfile is only called during teardown). After that, simply call cgGLBindProgram and render as many times are you want to. Have you tried doing this? The OpenGL implementations might treat the cgGLEnableProfile in different ways.

Comment: @ananthonline: I believe profiles need to be disabled before you draw anything with the fixed function pipe, no? At this point I'm not using shaders exclusively, though this is the eventual plan.

Comment: Can't you just CgGLBindProgram(0) to revert to the fixed function pipeline? Some googling produced the following link: http://objectmix.com/graphics/135925-disabling-cg-programs.html. Does either help?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `cgGLEnableProfile` before you call `cgGLBindProgram`. From your question it appears you do it the other way around.

From the Cg documentation for [`cgGLBindProgram`](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/cgGLBindProgram.html):

> cgGLBindProgram binds a program to the current state. The program must have been loaded with cgGLLoadProgram before it can be bound. Also, the profile of the program must be enabled for the binding to work. This may be done with the cgGLEnableProfile function.